# solr sunspot - searching belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I have a fabrics model that belongs to multiple other tables.

```
class Fabric < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :composition
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :style
  belongs_to :origin
  belongs_to :texture
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colours

  searchable do
    text :name, :boost => 5 
    text :description
    text :composition do
      composition.name
   end
    text :collection do
      collection.name
    end
   text :style do
     style.name
   end
   text :origin do
     origin.name
   end
   text :texture do
     texture.name
  end
   text :supplier do
      supplier.name
  end
  end
  end
```

I have setup all of the reverse associations (Has_many) etc.
However I do not seem to be able to get the fulltext search to query the name fields of all of these associated tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 @search = Fabric.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @fabrics = @search.results
```

Ross

Comment: can you show your search block? you need to reindex too.

Comment: is that what you where looking for, many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass block inside your fulltext to specify which fields you want to search on.

```
@search = Fabric.search do
  fulltext params[:search] do
    fields(:collection, :style, :origin)
  end
  .....
end
```

Here is how you index in your searchable block. Solr thinks in terms of document. It doesn't care it's an association or not.

```
searchable do 
  text :collection do 
    collection.text 
  end
end
```

Then reindex.

Check this out for more detail https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#full-text

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#setting-up-objects

Comment: if each of the associated tables :collection, :style etc, all have a text column :name, does this method search against those columns?

Answer (score 11):

In case some association can be nil, do not forget to test for that otherwise you will get error while rebuilding index

```
text :collection do 
  collection.name if collection
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't reindexed data after model update.

Run this command to reindex:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```