# full text search with rails sunspot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have  models such as

1. category(mobile,computer)
2. product(nokia,dell,apple)
3. models(c5)
4. posts

If i search for a mobile it should fetch from category model and match with posts and i should get a result.

Using [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=asciicast)

I created a text search but how do i search based on above criteria

I tried something like this in my category

This is my post model

```
belongs_to :product

    searchable do
        text :title,:description
        text :products do
            products.map(&:name)
        end

    end
```

Whether above searchable is correct but i didn't get any result

**Edit 1**

I found a [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768267/solr-sunspot-searching-belongs-to-association)

And i tried something like this

My controller

```
def index
    @search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        fields(:product)
      end
    end
    @posts = @search.results
  end
```

And My model

```
belongs_to :product
searchable do
        text :title,:description,:name
        text :product do
            product.name
        end
    end
```

It shows nothing

Comment: Did you index your data with `rake sunspot:reindex`?

Comment: Yes after `reindex` but every time when i update something to database it requires to `reindex` every time. How to solve it

Comment: Do you mean you get output when you reindex, but get no data when adds new instance of your model or when you change `searchable` block?

Comment: That's strange, when you change `searchable` you shouldn't get results from new fields, thats expected behaviour, but getting completely no results or no results on adding new instance is very strange indeed. Are you sure when you simply create and save (and do only that) new instance you  start getting no results from solr?

Comment: For test purpose directly i update my record in database directly not through rails.

Comment: I don't know behaviour of Solr in such case, but maybe it's getting into some 'panic mode' when you do changes in such way? Try doing it through rails to see if it fails. Also you can check Solr log (probably `log/sunspot-solr-development.log`) if there are any errors.

Comment: Ok ill check it. Is there any way to search each word instead of full text. Just now i come across the difficulty

Comment: Try looking into docs, you should find there anwers to many possible new questions: http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html and https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot