# Rails searching in association sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I have a model called job that i want to search for this the schema

```
  create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "experience"
    t.string   "contrat"
    t.text     "job_description"
    t.text     "profile_recherche"
    t.string   "job_contact"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

this is my job model

```
belongs_to :company

   searchable do
      text :job_title, boost: 4
      text :profile_recherche
      text :job_description
      text :experience
      text :contrat

    end
```

but the problem is that the contrat is not searchable

second thing i want to search a job by company name so for this i have followed this answer [solr sunspot - searching belongs_to association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768267/solr-sunspot-searching-belongs-to-association) but i don't get it working and i want also to make sector searchable

this is my company model

```
  has_many :sectorizations
has_many :sectors, through: :sectorizations

has_many :jobs
```

and this is my sector model

```
has_many :sectorizations
has_many :companies, through: :sectorizations
```

and this is my sectorization model

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :sector
```

i will appreciate any help

Comment: [... contrat is not searchable ..] Have you ran the rebuild task?

Comment: I have run rake sunspot:solr:reindex and it work now but search for association still don't work

Comment: The api documentation has everything you need. There is even an example (has_many comments) here: http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html#Setting_Up_Objects